# Powershell get-childitem against remote server

Tags: powershell

I would like to get size of user profiles across all servers in OU remotely, I tried this script, but without success

```
    $Exclude = @('admsupp','all users','public','Default','Default user')


$servers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Horizon8,OU=xxx,OU=x,OU=xxx,DC=xx,DC=xx" -Filter *

foreach ($server in $servers)
{

gci -force -path \\$server.dnshostname\c$\users -Exclude $Exclude -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { $_ -is [io.directoryinfo] } | % {
$len = 0
gci -recurse -force $_.fullname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % { $len += $_.length }
$_.fullname, '{0:N2} GB' -f ($len / 1Gb)
}


}
```

can someone advise please how to achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: Remove `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` so we can know the error you are getting, once you have the error / errors, update your question.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not getting any error, script exists immediately after start, because of that I have no idea how to troubleshoot it

Comment: when I run just this, its working fine 

gci -force -path \\server\c$\users -Exclude $Exclude -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { $_ -is [io.directoryinfo] } | % {
$len = 0
gci -recurse -force $_.fullname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % { $len += $_.length }
$_.fullname, '{0:N2} GB' -f ($len / 1Gb)
}

Comment: In order for `-Exclude` to work, you need to also append switch `-Recurse` **OR** have the path end in `\*`. You have obscured your `-Filter` on Get-ADComputer.. My guess is that what you are not showing us there is causing the script to fail immediately.

Comment: I am sorry I corrected to -filter *

Comment: and as I wrote, it is working without foreach statement...

Comment: @TomášNejtek `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` will prevent any error to be displayed, you need to remove both so we can know what's going on

Comment: I removed, but as I wrote, it fails immediately, without any error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you construct is wrong.
The way you write `\\$server.dnshostname\c$\users` will not give you what you think and you should either use a sub expression inside a double-quoted string:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$($server.DNSHostName)\c$\users"
```

or construct it using the `-f` Format operator like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path ('\\{0}\c$\users' -f $server.DNSHostName)
```

Then, because you don't want to use recursion in the first Get-ChildItem, the `-Exclude` parameter does not function and instead use the `-Directory` switch and a Where-Object clause after that to exclude the folders you do not want:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$($server.DNSHostName)\c$\users" -Directory | Where-Object { $Exclude -notcontains $_.Name }
```

---

As per your comment, if you have server names all starting with a single `letter` followed by one or more digits and you want to construct a longer path using that, you could do

```
# construct the path:
# if computername is 'V10testcomputer', this will result in'\\V10testcomputer\c$\Users\testcomputer\AppData'
$path = '\\{0}\c$\users\{1}\AppData' -f $server.DNSHostName, ($server.DNSHostName -replace '^[A-Z]\d+(.*)', '$1')
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory | Where-Object { $Exclude -notcontains $_.Name }
```

Comment: thank you for your help, can you advise me with one more thing?
I would like to modify path like this way
\\$($server.name)\c$\Users\$server.name.Split("V10")\AppData

example, if the $server.name would be V10testcomputer
\\V10testcomputer\c$\Users\testcomputer\AppData

Comment: @TomášNejtek Please see my edit to do just that. It uses regex to remove the first letter (a-z) followed by 1 or more digites from the computername

Comment: please see my last answer

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the way you construct the Path, see @Theo's answer.

But you can do it far more quickly with `Measure-Object` instead of another For-Each loop.
You don't have to test the `DirectoryInfo` type, unless you are still using PowerShell 2, simply use the `-Directory` parameter.

```
$Exclude = @('admsupp','all users','public','Default','Default user')

$servers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=Horizon8,OU=xxx,OU=x,OU=xxx,DC=xx,DC=xx" `
              -Filter * 

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    gci -Force -Path "\\$($server.dnshostname)\c$\users" -Exclude $Exclude `
        -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        % {
            $_.Fullname, '{0:N2} GB' -f ((gci -Recurse -Force $_.Fullname `
                             -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object `
                                     -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1Gb)
        }
}
```

I Suggest you to prefer this

```
$_.Fullname, (gci -Recurse -Force $_.Fullname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
                 Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum
```

because reusing this info is easier than text data

Answer (score 0):

@theo
Hi,
currently I am running this script

```
$Exclude = @('admsupp','all users','public','Default','Default user')

$servers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase "OU=xxx,OU=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx,DC=xxx" -Filter *

$path = '\\{0}\c$\users\{1}\AppData\roaming' -f $server.name, ($server.name -replace '^[A-Z]\d+(.*)', '$1')

foreach ($server in $servers) {

$colItems = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Exclude $Exclude | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | Sort-Object
foreach ($i in $colItems)
{
$subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum

$i.FullName + ”;” + “{0:N2}” -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1GB) + ” GB” >> C:\users\xxx\export.txt
$i.FullName + ”;” + “{0:N2}” -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1GB) + ” GB”
}


}
```

excludes are working fine like this, but the script failes immediately after start without any error message. Only thing that I have changed is the path regarding your advice:`$path = '\\{0}\c$\users\{1}\AppData\roaming' -f $server.name, ($server.name -replace '^[A-Z]\d+(.*)', '$1')`

Comment: The `$path` variable is outside your `foreach`, `$server` is `$null`. Furthermore, the user name is construct from the server name, this is weird and probably false.

Comment: thank you, the problem was the path variable outside of foreach, thank you!